# React-Router is refreshing page when I change the route in the address bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am using redux and react-redux to change the state of my application.

I have two components, `Login` and `Home`.

I will dispatch an action to update the state if the user is correctly logged and navigate him to the `Home` component. I am using an authguard in the route of `Home` component to check whether the user is logged or not.

But when I navigate to the `Home` component by typing the route in the address bar, the page is refreshing and the state changes to its initial values.

How can I maintain the state values even if I navigate to a component by using the address bar?

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to store the data in `localstorage` if you are navigating to a component by using the address bar. When you are navigating by address bar it is kind of like refreshing the page and the entire store is lost. You'll have to hydrate the store again for it to show the previous redux state.

You can use middlewares such as [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) or [redux-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-storage) which will save the redux store and hydrate the redux store on page reload.